# cordova inappbrowser doesn't load links inside app

Tags: cordova, url, view, onload, inappbrowser

I have an android app that when running loads an index.html on the server. This file redirects to another page:

```
window.open ('url', '_ blank', 'location = yes');
```

This page is loaded into the application and has a menu composed of `<a>` tags. When I click on a menu option it redirects me to other pages but loads them into the system browser and not into the app.

I installed the cordova-plugin-inappbrowser plugin.

I have tested `<a>` tags in the following ways:

```
echo "<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"window.open('"$url."','_ self','location=yes');\">Categ</a>";

echo "<a href=\"\" onclick=\"window.open('".$url."');\">Categ</a>";

echo "<a onclick=\"window.open('".$url."','_ self','location=yes');\">Categ</a>";
```

In the config.xml file I added:

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

What am I doing wrong? I can not figure out why it does not load the menu pages into the app.

Answer (score 1):

window.open is no longer supported.

Try this.

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

Comment: I had already tried that option but it didn't work.
The problem was that I needed to add the `<allow-navigation>` node to my config.xml file. 
I misunderstood `<allow-navigation>` with `<allow-intent>`.
Thank you.